# Pass orderBy or OrderByDescending as parameter

Tags: c#

I have method like this :

```
GetUsallyOpeningClosingHour(Func<OpeningDay, TimeSpan> groupByRule)
{
var openingClosingHours = listOfSpecificDayOfWeek.GroupBy(groupByRule).OrderByDescending(x => x.Key);
}
```

and the problem is that I can't stick all the time with `OrderByDescending` depends on groupByRule parameter sometimes it has to be orderByDescending or OrderBy

I don't want to depend on this parameter, so I could pass another one for that, 
Right now I call my method this way:

```
GetUsallyOpeningClosingHour(x => x.From)
```

or

```
GetUsallyOpeningClosingHour(x => x.To)
```

How can I pass orderBy type as well ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way is adding a parameter, which will specify an order in your collection.

```
public void GetUsallyOpeningClosingHour(
    Func<OpeningDay, TimeSpan> groupByRule, 
    bool orderByDesc = false)
{
    var groupedDays = listOfSpecificDayOfWeek.GroupBy(groupByRule);

    var openingClosingHours =
        orderByDesc
            ? groupedDays.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)
            : groupedDays.OrderBy(x => x.Key);
}
```

It could be a `boolean` or custom `enum` (I prefer enum, because it actually specifies a kind of ordering operation, while `boolean` specifies whether collection should be ordered by `desc` or not).

```
public enum OrderingType
{
    Ascending,
    Descending,
    None
}
```

Or you could provide an additional `Func`, which will perform an ordering operation. But its signature will be awkward.

```
public static void GetUsallyOpeningClosingHour(
    Func<OpeningDay, TimeSpan> groupByRule,
    Func<IEnumerable<IGrouping<TimeSpan, OpeningDay>>,
         IEnumerable<IGrouping<TimeSpan, OpeningDay>>> orderBy)
{
    var groupedDays = listOfSpecificDayOfWeek.GroupBy(groupByRule);
    var openingClosingHours = orderBy(groupedDays);
}
```

Comment: I was wondering how to create this monster with awkward signature, thanks

Comment: @kosnkov, btw, it's the worst one, I suppose, because signature will provide method implementation details to the higher level code, i.e incapsulation will be broken.

Comment: sure I know that, I must be stupied to apply this, but I was wondering how to do it, and now I get it, of course I will take bool parameter :)

Answer (score 7):

I guess you *could* create your own OrderBy extension that let you select ascending/descending based on a parameter.

Something like this:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    bool descending
)
{
    return descending ? source.OrderByDescending(keySelector)
                      : source.OrderBy(keySelector);
}
```

You can also use an enum instead of the boolean to make things more readable when calling this method.

Answer (score 3):

```
        public List<Book> Books(string orderField, bool desc, int skip, int take)
    {
        var propertyInfo = typeof(Book).GetProperty(orderField);

        return _context.Books
            .Where(...)
            .OrderBy(p => !desc ? propertyInfo.GetValue(p, null) : 0)
            .ThenByDescending(p => desc ? propertyInfo.GetValue(p, null) : 0)
            .Skip(skip)
            .Take(take)
            .ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of how this addresses the question. Code only answers can almost always benefit from the inclusion of some explanation of how they work and why they are a good solution, or what drawbacks they have.

Comment: @JasonAller this is self explained code, clear for any developer.

Answer (score 2):

This is the most direct way to parameterise for `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending`. Fortunately the type can be inferred for you by Visual Studio; unfortunately the type is long to write out. I added the `static void` and the initializer for `listOfSpecificDayOfWeek` so that this is easy to paste into a program for testing.

```
static void GetUsallyOpeningClosingHour(
  Func<OpeningDay, TimeSpan> groupByRule, 
  Func<IEnumerable<IGrouping<TimeSpan, OpeningDay>>, 
       Func<IGrouping<TimeSpan, OpeningDay>, TimeSpan>,
       IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<TimeSpan, OpeningDay>>> order)
{
  IEnumerable<OpeningDay> listOfSpecificDayOfWeek = null;
  var openingClosingHours = order(listOfSpecificDayOfWeek.GroupBy(groupByRule), x => x.Key);
}
```

You can call this function like this:

```
GetUsallyOpeningClosingHour(x => x.From, Enumerable.OrderByDescending);
GetUsallyOpeningClosingHour(x => x.From, Enumerable.OrderBy);
```

As other answers indicate, you can also just use a boolean flag to indicate ascending or descending order.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to pass in a parameter as there's no way for the method to know which direction you want to sort in based only on the parameter (eg. From/To).

```
public [return-type] GetUsallyOpeningClosingHour(Func<OpeningDay, TimeSpan> groupByRule, bool isAscending)
{
    var openingClosingHours = listOfSpecificDayOfWeek.GroupBy(groupByRule);

    if (isAscending)
    {
        openingClosingHours = openingClosingHours.OrderBy(x => x.Key);
    }
    else
    {
        openingClosingHours = openingClosingHours.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key);
    }

    // Return openingClosingHours?  It's not clear how you're using this variable.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my code sample:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAllbySearch(
            int pageNumber = 1, int pageSize = 10,
            Dictionary<string, dynamic> filterParams = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IIncludableQueryable<T, object>> include = null,
            bool allIncluded = false
            , Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> order = null)
        {
            var query = _entity.AsQueryable();

            if (include != null && !allIncluded)
            {
                query = include(query);
            }
            if (allIncluded && include == null)
            {
                foreach (var property in _context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).GetNavigations()
                    .Where(r => !r.IsCollection()))
                    query = query.Include(property.Name);
            }
            if (filterParams != null && filterParams.Any())
            {
                if (filterParams.Any(r => r.Value != null))
                {
                    var expression = GetSearchFilter(filterParams);
                    if (order != null)
                    {
                        return order(query.Where(expression));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return query.Where(expression));
                    }
                }
            }

            if (order != null)
            {
                return order(query);
            }
            else
            {
                return query;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Could you add explanation to what this does, how it answers the question.

Comment: in this function you can get list of entities by filter and pagination and orderby and include dynamically